# append text in google search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to append text in google search result using a custom chrome extension. but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

here is my manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches":["<all_urls>"],
      "js" : ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
```

contentscript.js:

```
function changeResultText(event) {
  $('h3.r').append('<b>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</b>');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', changeResultText);
```

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Every time you insert that `<b>` you will call the handler, over and over and over again.

Comment: try `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();` to make sure the event will not keep calling the other events that already attached here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example, you can set custom text, image on the top of every search results.

manifest.json:

```
{
...
"content_scripts": [
    {

        "js" : ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
        "css": ["contentscript.css"],
        "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls>" ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }
  ]
...
}
```

contentscript.js:

```
console.log("Custom Script Injected...");

// MutationObserver configuration data: Listen for "childList" mutations in the specified element and its descendants 
var config = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};

var regex = /<a.*?>[^<]*<\/a>/;


// Traverse 'rootNode' and its descendants and modify '<a>' tags 
function modifyLinks(rootNode) {

    var nodes = [rootNode];
    var replace = '';
    while (nodes.length > 0) {
        var node = nodes.shift();
        if (node.tagName == "A" &&   node.parentElement.parentElement.className == 'rc') {


        replace = "<div class=\"store-logo\">\r\n  <img src='any-logo.png' width='30' height='20' > </div>";
                        replace += "<div class=\"cashback-text\">Any Title</div>\r\n";
                        replace += node.innerHTML;
                        node.innerHTML = replace;


        } else {
            // If the current node has children, queue them for further processing, ignoring any '<script>' tags. 
            [].slice.call(node.children).forEach(function(childNode) {
                if (childNode.tagName != "SCRIPT") {
                    nodes.push(childNode);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}



// Observer1: Looks for 'div.search'
var observer1 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // For each MutationRecord in 'mutations'... 
    mutations.some(function(mutation) {
        // ...if nodes have beed added... 
        if (mutation.addedNodes && (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0)) {
            // ...look for 'div#search' 
            var node = mutation.target.querySelector("div#search");
            if (node) {
                // 'div#search' found; stop observer 1 and start observer 2 
                observer1.disconnect();
                observer2.observe(node, config);

                if (regex.test(node.innerHTML)) {
                    // Modify any '<a>' elements already in the current node 
                    modifyLinks(node);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});


// Observer2: Listens for '<a>' elements insertion 
var observer2 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes) {
            [].slice.call(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function(node) {
                // If 'node' or any of its desctants are '<a>'... 
                if (regex.test(node.outerHTML)) {
                    // ...do something with them 
                    modifyLinks(node);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

/* Start observing 'body' for 'div#search' */
observer1.observe(document.body, config);


//document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', observer1.observe(document.body, config));
```

contentscript.css:

```
.store-logo{ 
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 19px;
}

.cashback-text{  
    color: #f43632 !important; 
}
```